# Implementing a non-terrestrial calendar

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, calendar

As I was looking into solutions for another question, I found myself wondering whether it was possible to use .NET's [`Calendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to implement a calendar that wasn't based on Earthly conventions.

For instance, [Mars' day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timekeeping_on_Mars) is about 2.7% longer than a day here on Earth:

> A convention used by spacecraft lander projects to date has been to keep track of local solar time using a 24 hour "Mars clock" on which the hours, minutes and seconds are 2.7% longer than their standard (Earth) durations.

Is there any good way to implement a `MarsCalendar` such that the length of a second is different from the standard `GregorianCalendar`, and thus be able to use `DateTime` objects based on it for all the standard `AddDays()`, `AddHours()`, etc. functions?  <sub>(Note: Ideally, a solution - if one exists - would be applicable to any form of planetary object for which it is possible to define both "1 day" and "1 year" of consistent lengths. Mars makes for a great example, though)</sub>

Comment: hmmm that would be the first time I see [martians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian) dependant on our technology :P

Comment: seems quite interesting, we can use computer in mars too.

Comment: There should be a badge for "Best question of the day", and this should win it!

Comment: I suspect you'd need to subclass or roll your own `ExtraPlanetaryDateTime` object with the needed properties and methods to use different multiplication factors, and then create subclasses for `MarsDateTime`, etc., with the specific values. Shouldn't be too difficult. Of course the only meaning this would have is when compared relative to Earth's calendar.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin - Interesting idea.  I can definitely see that as part of a solution.  It wouldn't account for leap days, the length of a year, or any of that, though, which is what the `Calendar` handles.  So some way to combine a `ExtraPlanetaryCalendar` implementation with a `ExtraPlanetaryDateTime`, maybe?

Comment: Wouldn't leap years and lengths of a year be the same as currently, since you're only multiplying the relative length of each tick, therefore second, therefore minute, etc., with all other factors being constant?

Comment: @DavidKhaykin And since `DateTime` is a value type and can't be subclassed, you'd have to roll out your own from scratch. And that means rolling out a custom class for every class that depends on `DateTime`. So using that approach, I suppose the answer would be no, you wouldn't be able to use c#'s `Calendar`, because it's coupled to `DateTime`.

Comment: I think it's appropriate for DateTime to be a value type. I'd look at making ExtraPlanetaryDateTime a value type as well, with the requirement that an ExtraPlanetaryCalendar is an essential part of each value's meaning.  I think an ExtraPlanetaryTimeSpan would ultimately also be required, and would also be interpretable as no more than a number of ticks without the help of a Calendar or ExtraPlanetaryCalendar.

Comment: Agreed on all counts. @dcastro you're correct since you'd roll your own 'everything' in this instance, the literal answer might be no but a solution that closely emulates the current .net implementation is certainly feasible.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin - Once you get up to anything larger than a day, the 2.7% conversion breaks down. Hours/minutes/seconds are based on rotational speed, while Days/Months/Years are based on orbit speed.  On the other hand, `Calendar` already supports setting arbitrary numbers of day per year.

Comment: Aaah ok, I'm a little bit rusty in my inter-planetary C# reasoning skills :) Good point. How would you even determine a gregorian style calendar for other planets? Maybe there isn't a need for leap years on  Jupiter, for example? (Interesting aside: I'm sure there's some astronomer/scientist out there that's probably tried to and/or succeeded in defining such constructs for other planets. Possibly even a formula?

Comment: @DavidKhaykin - It's always possible, but it'd be rare for the precise number of hours in a year to divide evenly into days, unless you calculated hours based on the length of a year instead of length of a day.  Of course, the *way* in which you adjust could be completely different.  Leap days every month? Leap hours every 5 days? Every third even numbered hour has 3 extra minutes?  All possible (though not necessarily feasible).  Also, Mars has a proposed [Darian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darian_calendar), although no one uses it for anything.

Comment: Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx  (obvious post is obvious, sorry). And then maybe consider putting together a MarsCalender implementation under System.Globilization?

Comment: FYI, it's not a C# `Calendar` class. The same class can be used by VB.NET or any other .NET language. It's the .NET `Calendar` class.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Valid point.  I work with C#, so I think of it as C#'s, but that's purely my bias.

Comment: @PseudoNym01 - Yeah, that's where I started.  But that doesn't address the inherent assumption that a "day" has 24 hours, and as far as I can tell, `Calendar` implementations can't change that.

Comment: This is kind of interesting. ANY earth-based calendar would simply be pointless in the context of tracking time on Mars. In Earth time, Mars rotates in 29 hrs, 39 minutes, 35 seconds. A Martian year is 1.8809 Earth years. But if Mars is your frame of reference, all of that is meaningless. Your day is just however long it takes for Mars to rotate about its axis one time. Divide that into a convenient number of slices, you get "hours." Divide those, you get minutes, divide those and you get seconds. The divisions are just mathematically handy, with no meaning beyond what we ascribe to them.

Comment: Adding to the confusion, a "Year" is just the number of times you can divide a planet's rotational period into its orbital period, right? That's a different value on Mars than it is on Earth. Even on Earth, we resort to leap years as a fudge factor to make up for the fact that the period of an Earth day does not divide evenly into the period of an Earth year, right? So on another planet, like Mars, you'd still need leap years, or maybe leap months or weeks, as somebody else alluded to, but the basis would be entirely different than on Earth. The Earth calendar is very much bound to Earth.

Comment: @Craig seems to have the most correct insight so far I think

Comment: Following on @Craig's thought, is it true that the Earth is more or less in the same coordinates every December 31st 11:59pm?  What is the equivalent location for Mars?

Comment: The earth is only at more or less the same coordinates _relative to the sun_ at the same date and time every year.  The sun itself is whipping around the galaxy's center of mass, although for all I know (not being an actual astrophysicist or anything), the sun is part of a local group of objects whose center of mass is whipping around the galaxy's center of mass, in which case the sun's position within that smaller body may well be shifting, which in turn means that the rate of time in the neighborhood of the sun itself probably isn't quite constant. Time is only really relevant where you are.

Answer (score 13):

There are several non-Gregorian calendar classes derived from `System.Globalization.Calendar` within the Globalization namespace (i.e. [`JapaneseCalendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.japanesecalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). You should be able to implement your own. I'd whip up a sample, but there are 16 abstract methods in the Calendar class...

You might even be able to simply derive your class from `GregorianCalendar` and just override the [`GetMilliseconds(DateTime)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, returning the base's return value multiplied by `1.027d`.

Comment: Interesting.  Would that propagate up to larger time increments, or would I have to override each one separately?

Comment: After a bit more research into the other calendars, I'd guess that GregorianCalendar and the other calendars use the Ticks property of each DateTime passed to it for the math behind all of its GetX methods.
It gets complicated with DateTime values, because the DayOfYear, DayOfMonth, and DayOfWeek properties are clamped to earthly values. There are no calendars built-in to the System.Globalization namespace that have **more** than 12 months or more than 365 days (though some have less days), so I'm guessing those clamped values can't be overridden, so you might need your own DateTime structure.